# cannot execute javascript new Function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a function that is created using "new Function"

```
jsonTransformed = new Function("return function(value, axis) {return value + ' degree';}")();
jsonTransformed('kk');
console.log(jsonTransformed('kk'));
```

1. The jsonTransformed('kk'); donot run and print anything on console.
2. The console.log(jsonTransformed('kk')); run the code and console is printed.

What am I doing wrong here? I tried search but was unable to find similar questions.

UPDATE: Answer accepted below.

Comment: This is running in the console just fine.  Not sure what you're trying to do with this.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/walezakuya/edit?js,console

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: The second line simply returns a string `"kk degree"`. It's not assigned to anything or used in any other way. Third line prints it to the console, as expected.

Comment: Opps thanks, mine was a bit slow and had syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jsonTransformed` function isn't writing anything to anywhere.

The reason why you're able to get something when you use `console.log(jsonTransformed('kk'));` is because the value that's being returned is being written to the console.

If you wanted to return the value on the DOM you'll have to create a selector to write it there.

---

**EDIT after your edit**

It would be easier to create your functions like this, it's easier to manage.

```
function jsonTransformed(value, axis){
    return value + ' degree';
}
```

And when you want to call it this is all you would have to do.

```
jsonTransformed("foo", "bar");
```

Assigning it to a variable

```
var foo = jsonTransformed("for", "bar");
```

Returning data to the console

```
console.log(jsonTransformed("for", "bar"));
```

Comment: Yes, if you don't write the returned value anywhere you won't see it. If you want to see values being returned from your function create a `console.log()` inside of your function so no matter how you use it you'll get something returned.